# Automatically close messagebox in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, messagebox

I am currently developing an application in C# where I display a MessageBox. How can I automatically close the message box after a couple of seconds?

Comment: Indeed - a timer - and your own custom dialog rather than a MessageBox, otherwise you'll have to start fiddling with sending events to the MessageBox in order to get it to close, I'd imagine.

Comment: For C++ Check out this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66004457/6219626

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will need to create your own Window, with the code-behind  containing a loaded handler and a timer handler as follows:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.Interval = 3000;
    t.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(t_Elapsed);
    t.Start();
}

void t_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(()=>
    {
        this.Close();
    }),null);
}
```

You can then make your custom message box appear by calling ShowDialog():

```
MyWindow w = new MyWindow();
w.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Which of the available Timer types is that?

Answer (score 3):

The System.Windows.MessageBox.Show() method has an overload which takes an owner Window as the first parameter. If we create an invisible owner Window which we then close after a specified time, it's child message box would close as well.

Here is the complete answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20098381/2190520

Answer (score 1):

```cs
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern int MessageBoxTimeout(IntPtr hwnd, String text, String title,
                                     uint type, Int16 wLanguageId, Int32 milliseconds);

MessageBoxTimeout((System.IntPtr)0 ,"Message", "Title",0,0, 1000);
//last parameter timeout in milisecond
```

Answer (score -1):

This library https://github.com/DmitryGaravsky/AutoClosingMessageBox implements a MessageBox which closes itself after a specified time.

Also see this stackoverflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14522952/4856020