# How To Close MessageBox Programmatically in WP8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm aware that there are already [**questions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362235/automatically-close-messagebox-in-c-sharp) questions asked regarding closing a MessageBox programmatically . But the solution to those questions is to use a timer.

I am trying to develop an NFC application, so when i create a MessageBox, it contains a message `Please Tap Your NFC`. So technically, the Timer isn't helpful. I need a way to close or dispose a MessageBox.

Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom window yourself as described in the question you linked. However, instead of a timer you can and include a `Hide` method which you can call once NFC connection event occurs.

Alternatively, you could get [Coding4Fun toolkit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/) and use `MessagePrompt` class which already includes a Hide method.

Comment: Thanks! Coding4Fun toolkit's `MessagePrompt` worked like charm!

Answer (score 0):

From [lieska](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1990175/lieska) at [MessageBox.Show in App Closing/Deactivated events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419884/messagebox-show-in-app-closing-deactivated-events/16400384#16400384)

> Register BackKeyPress event on RootFrame.
>
> ```
> RootFrame.BackKeyPress += BackKeyPressed;
> private void BackKeyPressed(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
>     {
>         var result = (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to exit XXXXX?", "Application Closing", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel));
>         if (result == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
>         {
>             // Cancel default navigation
>             e.Cancel = true;
>         }
> }
> ```