# Toaster message in windows phone 8.1 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, toast

I am developing windows phone 8.1 app using VS 2013.

I want to show toaster message for a period of time like toaster message in Andriod apps.
What I am getting is Alert message and notification message. Both require user action at some point to closed the message.

What I want is to automatically close the message asynchronously .

Any help/suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ilaiya.

Answer (score 1):

The toast API for WP8.1 is described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj662938(v=vs.105).aspx). The message can be clicked by the user, dismissed or ignored. But you can only retrieve a "click event" by configuring a URI for your toast (eg *page1.xaml*, which will be launched at click). 
You can't know if the toast is dismissed or ignored, and you can't close it by yourself (with code)

Comment: Thanks bviale. That's nice. But I have to  search for some other options. Is there any other API which will be optimal for my requirement that may not be a toaster?

Comment: Are you looking for an in-app notification or a notification while your app is in background ?

Comment: I am not at all looking for kinda notification. Instead I want a message box like android toaster. It should close after a period of time.

Comment: There is no such control natively in WP, as an alternative, I suggest you this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16848986/how-to-close-messagebox-programmatically-in-wp8 which refers to this toolkit : http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/

Cheers